# tomcat installed in remote Ubuntu server doesn't connect using http://myIpAdress:8080

Tags: apache, tcp, firewall, ubuntu-22.04, tomcat10

I have a remote server : Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed Tomcat 10 based on this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-10-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-4-accessing-the-web-interface) .

tomcat is running:

```
root@server:/opt/tomcat/conf# sudo systemctl status tomcat
● tomcat.service - Tomcat
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-07-18 09:42:35 UTC; 3s ago
   Process: 18433 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 18440 (java)
     Tasks: 31 (limit: 18973)
    Memory: 108.9M
       CPU: 3.399s
    CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
            └─18440 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/l>
```

Also the port 8080 is open and used by tomcat:

```
root@server:/opt/tomcat/conf# netstat -nat|grep :8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN

root@server:/opt/tomcat/conf# sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    18606 tomcat   42u  IPv6 108428      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

The firewall is desabled :

```
root@server:/opt/tomcat/conf# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

When I type `http://myIpAdress`  in my browser, it shows this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu6Vn.png

But when I try to connect in browser using   `http://myIpAdress:8080`  it doesn't work :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k77az.png

Have you any idea why tomcat doesn't work on browser?

Comment: Is your network really only IPv6?

Comment: Please how can I check this?

Comment: I'm wrong - the `tcp6` in your output had me concerned.  Perhaps it is your client Windows machine?  I see [these instructions](https://help.mashme.io/support/solutions/articles/29000036898-how-to-see-if-windows-firewall-is-blocking-a-port-or-program) to show you blocked ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port 8080 was open and the firewall was desabled, But the server's administrator was blocking the connection to this port. It works fine after the adminitrator's intervention.